# Exception catching with multiple file reading in java

Tags: java, exception

To work with multiple file reading and output, what's the best way to handle exceptions in try catch block.

```
try{
  BufferReader br1 = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(fileName1));
  BufferReader br2 = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(fileName2));
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  System.err.println("Not found file " + fileName1);
  System.err.println("Not found file " + fileName2);
}
```

If there is only one file not found, then the warning message isn't quite right. If I create another try catch block, then it can solve the problem, but it seems awkward. What's the best way in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Separate try catch blocks should work. It is not awkward.  I think it is okay. But depends on individual coding "tastes". Otherwise make separate methods that return reader. Or separate methods to check if file exists. Or check in same method and throw exception if file not found. Do remember to close the readers in finally block

Comment: What is the type of fileName1, fileName2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `createBufferedReader(String fileName)` method then you won't have that problem.

Sample:

```
private BufferReader createBufferedReader(String fileName) {
   BufferReader br = null;
   try {
     br = new BufferReader(new FileReader(fileName));
     return br;
   } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.err.println("Not found file" + fileName);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't like this pretty much because even if it does its dirty job, wrapping a piece of functionality in a method should imply that either the method succeeds or fails throwing an exception. It shall not print to stderr.

Comment: Good approach, but I would rather propagate the exception so the most external layer can treat it accordingly.

Comment: Throwing FileNotFoundException would be of no help since then we have the original problem again. The point is that he/she should just divide the two try-catch blocks, no more, no less.

Comment: This solution looks sensible, if the number of files are big; otherwise, just use try catch() based on others' suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: No, if the number of files is big, you are going to loop through an array in any case. And then, you need just a single try-catch block. Another problem with this approach is that the control flow isn't interrupted by a file that couldn't be opened, you only have some stuff on `stderr` and a `null` pointer returned (to be checked, then!)

Comment: Just unrelated note: This code does not compile since there is no constructor for BufferedReader that takes a String.

Comment: @user697911 if the number of files are big, why not have the list of files in a collection and call this method inside a loop for each element

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan Sorry I meant InputStreamReader(String)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper method to create a `BufferedReader` and call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I find it sensible to just separate the two `try`-`catch` blocks, no more, no less.

The solution provided by Nappa The Saiyan does its dirty job, but wrapping a piece of functionality in a method should imply that either the method succeeds or fails throwing an exception. It shall not print to `stderr`. Throwing the exception again in the wrapper method will give the original problem again.

Really, go separate the `try`-`catch` blocks. And if you have `n > 2` filenames, just write a for loop on an array of filenames and customize your error message so that it prints the number of the file that could not be read. Then you'll have a single `try`-`catch`.